# MATLAB Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods

Tags: matlab

everyone. 
I do not know what is going wrong. I tried to access all files in a folder and my code is as following:

```
dirList = dir('*.SAC');
for n = 1:length(dirList)
  w(n) = loadsac(w,dirList(n).name);
end
```

Output:
Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods.

Could somebody tells me the reason for it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you getting this error from line 3 above, or is it being thrown from within `loadsac`? There's more information about the error than just what you listed here. Please include all of it.

Comment: what is `w` and what is `loadsac`? Have you examined the contents of `dirList` manually to ensure you're getting what you expect (i.e., not hidden or temp files that might have the same extension)?

Comment: Hi, I have checked dirList(n) and I am sure I have already got what I want. And the problem confusing me is that I can run this program in MATLAB terminal but not in script. w means waveform. The loadsac is basically a function provided by GISMO toolbox to load sac file.

Comment: How do you initialize `w`, and are you meant to both pass it into `loadsac` and modify it with the return value?

Comment: Maybe you have a class or something, named also `dirList`? That can explain the error, like you try to use `name` as a method that not exist..